# iPhone : Problems with UIScrollView when switching between UITextFields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am having 15 textFields which are on the same view.

Now as the keyboard comes up, I resize my scroll view in order to make the textFields which are on the lower portion of the view to be visible.

I observed that switching from one textField to another brings the scrollView to its original frame.

How can i avoid my scrollview's frame from resetting everytime I resign the first responder from textField?

```
         // Here I am resetting the scrollView size so the textField do not hide behind the keyboard.

       - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
          {
          [scroll setFrame:CGRectMake(503, 123, 515, 275)]; 
          [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(515, 550)];  
          }

         // Here I am resizing the scrollView so after returning the keyboard the scrollView gets its original hight
      - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
        {
      [scroll setFrame:CGRectMake(503, 123, 515, 570)]; 
         [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(515, 560)]; 
        }
```

Comment: paste the code you use to switch between the text fields if any or a code that get triggered when you switch

Answer (score 0):

Why do you change the content size for the `scrollView` each time?

```
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(515, 560)];
```

It would be better to have a fixed `contentSize` for it and change the `contentOffset` of the `scrollView` based on the `textField`

Comment: because at any point if i press return key of keyboard. It will resize the scrollView size.

Comment: Why do you want to change the size wont it be sufficient to change the contentOffset

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re confused about how `contentSize` works -- if the contents of your scrollview are not ever changing (the text fields are not *removed* when you show the keyboard), then you shouldn’t change the contentSize. Setting the `frame`, as you are doing, should be sufficient.